# Why is *p++ different from *p += 1?

Tags: c

Consider:

```
void foo1(char **p) { *p++; }
void foo2(char **p) { *p += 1; }
```

and

```
char *s = "abcd";
char *a = s; 
foo1(&a); 
printf("%s", a); //abcd
```

but if I use `foo2()` instead of:

```
char *a = s; 
foo2(&a); 
printf("%s", a); //bcd
```

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Because `*p++` is the same as `*(p++)`

Comment: [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Comment: Also try `void foo3(char **p) { (*p)++; }`

Comment: enjoy your nice question badge :-)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The key is the precedence of the `+=` and the `++` operator. The `++` has a higher precedence than the `+=` (in fact, assignment operators have the second lowest precedence in C), so the operation

```
*p++
```

means dereference the pointer, then increment the pointer **itself** by 1 (as usually, according to the rules of pointer arithmetic, it's not necessarily one byte, but rather `sizeof(*p)` regarding the resulting address). On the other hand,

```
*p += 1
```

means increment the value **pointed to by the pointer** by one (and do nothing with the pointer itself).

Comment: You did such a great job of explaining it, but could you please add in one detail *p++ increments the pointer itself by 1 "unit", so a char pointer might increment by one, while an int pointer might increment by 4, etc, depending on implementation specifics.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: I don't really see the relevance, that's just normal pointer arithmetic and not the focus of the question.

Comment: @EdwinBuck whether a pointer is an int or a char, when you increment it, it increases by one. The actual address that represents that pointer may change more than one byte, due to the size of the pointer however.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII We're both right, but we are talking about different 1's.  One unit, or `sizeof(*p)` is still a 1 in some scale, but if you look at the binary value stored in `p` the actual value is not always going to be "+1" in binary arithmetic.

Comment: The representation of the pointer, which is the simple memory address in many C implementations, should not be confused with its value, which is its meaning in the C context. `p++` does increase the value by one. Its effect on the representation of that value is irrelevant for the purposes of this question, the same way that it is irrelevant that adding 1 to the float `1.f` typically changes the representation by 8,388,608.

Comment: @EricPostpischil of course :) But I'M sure Edwin Buck was referring to the pointer as an unsigned integer value, as much pointer arithmetic papers explain it...

Comment: @H2C03: And would Edwin Buck criticize an answer about floating point arithmetic with a request to explain that the representation might change by 8,388,608, depending on implementation specifics? Would anybody give it any credence? No, because the representation is clearly irrelevant to the semantics. It is only because pointers are so temptingly close to addresses that people confuse the two. Because of this, we should encourage mentally separating the representation and the value, not conflating them.

Comment: @H2C03: For this question, I would not mention bytes or addresses and simply say “… means increment the pointer by one element (of the type it points to)”. It is clear, it refers only to the value within C, and it distinguishes increments of pointers to different types.

Comment: @H2CO3 comma `,` has the lowest precedence, and not the assignment operators. +1 for the explanation.

Comment: Just to check if I understood the answer one more question: So *p++ is equal to p += sizeof(*p)?

Comment: @Shimu Not at all. It's equivalent with `*(p += 1)`.

Answer (score 28):

Precedence. The postfix `++` binds tighter than the prefix `*` so it increments `p`. The `+=` is at the low end of the precedence list, along with the plain assignment operator, so it adds 1 to `*p`.

Answer (score 0):

Precedence of prefix ++ and * is same. Associativity of both is right to left. Precedence of postfix ++ is higher than both * and prefix ++. Associativity of postfix ++ is left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with `*p += 1`

I will try to answer this from a bit of a different angle... Step 1 Let's look at the operators and the operands: In this case it is one operand (the pointer p), and we have two operators, in this case * for dereferencing and += 1 for increment. Step 2 which has the higher precedence * has higher precedence over +=

---

`*P++`
This one is a bit trickier... maybe even wicked
Again we have one operand (p the pointer) and two operators, only now the * for dereference and ++ post increment are of the same precedence. (In some tables the ++ in a post is a higher precedence.)

Step 1 Let's look at the operators and the operands: In this case it is the operand, and you have two operators, in this case * for dereferencing and ++ for increment. Step 2 which has the higher precedence? ++ has higher precedence over * Note: even if they have the SAME precedence they associate right to left, again, the ++ is before *
Step 3 (the tricky part...) Where is ++ ? it is to the right side of the operand, which means **POST Increment** In this case, the compiler take a 'mental note' to perform the increment **AFTER** it is done with all the other operators... 
What after means? It means that it will only apply the increment as the very very very last step before the next ';' so it will be done with all other operators that are on the same 'line' 
note: if it was *++p then it will do it BEFORE any other operator on the same line so in this case, it is as equivalent to taking two of the processor's register, one will hold the value of the dereferenced *p and the other will hold the value of the incremented p++, the reason in this case there are two, is the POST activity... This is where in this case it is tricky, and it looks like a contradiction. One would expect the ++ to take precedence over the *, which it does, only that the POST means that it will be applied only after ALL other operands, BEFORE the next ';' token...

Like I said, the tricky part is that any increment that is to the right of an operand will be set aside, and will be applied as the LAST operation before it moves on to the next line...