# What is the difference between *myptr++ and *(myptr++) in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am using C.

Say I have a pointer to a integer called *myptr

`int *myptr;`

What would then be the difference between:

```
*myptr++
```

and...

```
*(myptr++)
```

Thanks
Dan

Comment: first one you are incrementing the the value the pointer myprt++ points to , the other you are getting the value of the next address that myprt points to

Comment: I have answered almost the same question not so long ago: possible duplicate of [Why is \*p++ different from \*p += 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221396/why-is-p-different-from-p-1)

Comment: have you tried it on your machine?

Comment: To me these are identical. Instead (*myptr)++; would be different.

Comment: I must say it is not good practice to rely on [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) though. Always use parantheses. That would greatly help any people looking at your code in the future.

Comment: @AnishRam Well, this is so idiomatic... Each and every libc implementation of `strlen()` has something like `while (*s++) len++;` in it.

Comment: @H2CO3, So are you saying you'd rather see `while (*s++) len++;` than `while (*(s++)) len++;`?

Comment: @AnishRam Yes, exactly.

Comment: Operator precedence games are nice, but 3 months later when you're trying to fix a bug fast, you will regret not having parantheses. So please use them from the start!

Comment: @Torp `*pointer++` is a C idiom. You will encounter it in the code of others even if you do not write it yourself, so you have to know what it does. You can do what you want for your own code.

Comment: @Torp Within limits. Some precedences are so fundamental that using parentheses only confuses. Would you write `int a = b + (c*d);` or `int a = b + c*d;`? Whether `*ptr++` is so fundamental as `+` and `*` is a question. I tend towards yes.

Comment: @Torp `*myptr++` is a very common C idiom, indeed. Unnecessary parenthesizing decreases readability.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `++` has higher precedence than `*`, there is **no difference** between the two.

Comment: Thank you. I was starting to get worried, seeing the wrong answer in one comment and two answers.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You are welcome. I wasn't sure if I just misread the question, and I even tried it with a string and a char pointer before posting, but apparently I was right.

Comment: @H2CO3 Mate,if there is no difference between the two then how would you explain the output of the program I have posted in my answer?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Are your 'practical tests' similar to those of Sheer Fish (i.e. http://ideone.com/2l51A9 )?

Comment: @SheerFish [Here's a correct sample code snippet.](http://ideone.com/KcVdrc) You can see that these are identical.

Comment: @H2CO3 PascalCuoq already explained the whole thing to me.I saw where I had gone wrong in the code.That's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 He used an integer array to illustrate his point though.Here are his and mine programs:  http://ideone.com/HI31dJ    , http://ideone.com/2l51A9

Comment: @SheerFish the code in your link increments the same variable (myptr) twice in the program hence your getting different results. the result of a postfix++ expression is a temporary rvalue object.