# Why doesn't *list++ or *(list++) work for list[4], but works fine for a pointer assigned the value of list?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I get the error `" lvalue required as increment operand|"` for both the `printf()` statements in the following program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int list[4]={12,22,32,42};

 printf("The result of *list++ is %d",*list++);

 printf("\nThe result of *(list++) is %d",*(list++));

 return 0;
 }
```

But in the following program `*myptr++` and `*(myptr++)` works fine for a pointer `myptr` which is assigned the base-address of `list`. [Ideone Link](http://ideone.com/HI31dJ)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int list[4]={12,22,32,42},*myptr;
 myptr=list;

 printf("The result of *myptr++ is %d",*myptr++);

 myptr=list;
 printf("\nThe result of *(myptr++) is %d",*(myptr++));
 }
```

Why is there a discrepancy between the two?What is the explanation?This question cropped in my find after going through the following question posted a few minutes back.Look for `H2CO3`'s answer.

[What is the difference between *myptr++ and *(myptr++) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262196/what-is-the-difference-between-myptr-and-myptr-in-c)

Comment: Because arrays and pointers are not same.

Comment: @AlokSave We posted at the exact same moment! Neat.

Comment: @AlokSave First time any communication with Alok Save.I only saw his photo on an aircraft.

Comment: @H2CO3: Great minds think alike and at times alike :D. Sheer: JFYI, It is not an aircraft, it is a train. If you notice the photo minutely the seats are facing each other. i have never seen that in a aircraft :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `list` is an array, not a pointer. Pointer arithmetic operations are defined for pointers, but not for arrays. A name of an array can be used to produce a pointer - for example, in expressions like `myptr = list`, but that does not mean that an array itself can be used as a pointer. In particular, array is not a modifiable `lvalue`, which is a fancy way of saying that you cannot reassign the array itself (although you can assign array's *value*).

Comment: Arrays are lvalues, but not _modifiable lvalues_.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the comment! I edited the answer to reflect  your point.

Answer (score 2):

Because pointers are not arrays.

---

You cannot increment an array. Just think about it, it doesn't make sense. An array is not a pointer, and it cannot be treated as one. That's why the C standard mandates that it's not a modifiable lvalue (which is needed for anything you want to change).

Comment: What is the plain-English explanation of the errors I mentioned `lvalue required as increment operand|`

Comment: @SheerFish [Lvalue explanation on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)) Basically, an array cannot be modified, only its elements.

Comment: I want to be a bit petty for a moment - *why* doesn't it make sense? OK, `sizeof` won't work, and you can potentially lose all your references to it. but that is exactly what happens with function parameters and `malloc`ed arrays.

Comment: @Elazar Huh? `sizeof()` works perfectly for arrays too. And why doesn't it make sense? Because an array is not a "scalar", if I'm permitted to use such loose terminology. An array is the ensemble of its elements, and it isn't merely a memory location (which is, after all, an integer).

Comment: @H2CO3 I meant `sizeof(a)` will be `sizeof(void*)` instead its size in memory. A malloced array is not a scalar too, but all you have is a pointer to it. Less type-safe, a bit more orthogonal and simple to learn.

Comment: @Elazar "A malloced array is not a scalar too, but all you have is a pointer to it" - that's the point. How would you increment an array behind that pointer?

Comment: something like make `int a[4];` mean actually `int _a[4], *a = _a;`.
There won't be such a type, "array". just pointers.

Comment: @Elazar I have absolutely no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29057/discussion-between-elazar-and-h2co3)

Answer (score 1):

Array is not a pointer. An array is just a continuous memory. When you mention the array's name in an expression, it "decays" to the number (of pointer type) representing its start address. This number cannot be incremented, decremented or assigned into - it is not an `lvalue` - since the place in which the array resides does not change.

say you have

```
int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

If, in some miraculous way, you happen to know exactly what will be that address - 0x1000 for example - you can replace *any* occurance of `a` in the code with ((int*)(0x1000)).

the statement `*a++=5` turns into 2 statements:

```
*a=5;
a++;
```

which as we say, is equivalent to:

```
*((int*)(0x1000))=5;
((int*)(0x1000))++;
```

Now, what does `*((int*)(0x1000))=5` mean? this is easy: write 5 at address 0x1000. Because  the expression *(pointer value) *is* an lvalue. but what does `((int*)(0x1000))++` mean? well, I dont know. You cannot increment 0x1000.

Comment: "an array is an address of its start address" - no, it isn't; "but it is not possible to do pointer arithmetic on it." - well, `int arr[3]; *(arr + 1) = 42;`

Comment: I fixed the first sentence - it was not what I meant. in your example you do pointer arithmetic with the value the array decays into.

Comment: I'm aware of that, perhaps it would be useful to explain that a bit more to OP.

Comment: Instead of deleting, I tried to improve it. @H2CO3 please tell me if it's still not clear (or wrong).

Answer (score -1):

In most cases you can use simple assumption that `int list[4]` is equal to `int * const list`. So, it's *not modifiable*.

Also remember that this simple assumption doesn't work when you get `sizeof(list)`. For example:

```
int list[4];
size_t s = sizeof(list); // s = sizeof(int)*4
```

but

```
int * const list;
size_t s = sizeof(list); // s is equal to size of pointer
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Answer is improved, is it ok now?