# Why can't I do *value++; to increment one to the value in that memory location?

Tags: c++, pointers

I understand that for it to works it needs to be

```
void increment(int *value)
{
    (*value)++;
}
```

This is because it needs brackets due to how precedence works (correct me if i'm wrong). But how come when I do the following, no compile error happens? The value isn't changed which is to be expected because there are no brackets, but what exactly is this changing?

```
void increment(int *value)
{
    *value++;
}
```

Comment: It's changing `value`.

Comment: Incrementing the pointer

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221396/why-is-p-different-from-p-1/12221425#12221425)

Answer (score 7):

`value` is a pointer to an integer. The rules of pointer arithmetic say that if you do an operation like `value++`, then afterwards it will point to `value + sizeof(int)` (in terms of bytes).

What's happening here is you would be dereferencing `value` to get some rvalue which you just throw away, **and then** incrementing `value` (not the thing it's pointing to, rather, the pointer itself).

Answer (score 2):

```
*value++;
```

It's de-referencing the value at the location pointed to by `value` and increments the pointer `value` due to post-increment. Effectively, it same as `value++` since you are discarding the value returned by the expression.

```
But how come when I do the following, no compile error happens?
```

Because it's a valid statement and you are just discarding the value returned by the expression. Same way, you could have statements like:

```
"Random string";

 42;
```

and they are valid and would compile fine (but useless).

We discard a lot of standard library functions' return values. E.g. `memset()` returns `void *` to the memory that was set but we rarely use it. This is not so intuitive, but it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

As per [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of operators,

`++` precedes `*`

Hence, it is executed as

`value++`  and `*` of it. Effectively, `*(value++)`

`value++` will return you the address of `value + (size of datatype pointed at)` i.e. `value + (size of int)` in this case.

Unless your `value` is pointing to an array, you are probably picking up a garbage value and dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

while not precisely the answer: from K&R C this is how memcopy can be implemented. if you understand the precedences that are happening you'll be able to answer your question yourself.

```
void *memcpy(char *ptr1, char *ptr2, size_t n) {
  void *ret = ptr1;
  while (n >0) {
    *ptr1++ = *ptr2++;
    n--;
  }
  return ret;
}
```